# Quantstrat sigPeak error: "k must be a non-negative integer"

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

I am trying to use a `sigPeak` signal and my code for adding this is:

```
add.signal(strategy=strat.id, name='sigPeak',
           arguments=list(column='ADX.ADX', direction="peak", data=quote(mktdata)),
           label='ADX.peak')
```

However, when I run `applySignals(..., applyIndicators(..))` right after adding that one, I get an error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : k must be a non-negative integer
```

I believe it is due to a *contradictio in codicum* in the following lines of `quantmod` and `quantstrat`:

Quantstrat, in the definition of `sigPeak`:

```
Lag(ret_sig,-1)
```

Quantmod, in the definition of `Lag.quantmod.OHLC` as that is the one that is used on XTS objects:

```
if(k.e<0||k.e!=as.integer(k.e)) stop("k must be a non-negative integer")
```

Does this mean that with the current versions of quantmod and quantstrat, `sigPeak` just doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure when that function was in a working state. That line was added in revision 588 in March 2011. Before that, the state of the function was:

```
sigPeak <- function(label,data,column, direction=c("peak","bottom")){
    colNum<-match.names(column,colnames(data))
    direction=direction[1] # only use the first]
    switch(direction,
           "peak"   = { Lag(data[,colNum],2) < Lag(data[,colNum],1) & Lag(data[,colNum],1) > data[,colNum] } ,
           "bottom","valley" = { Lag(data[,colNum],2) > Lag(data[,colNum],1) & Lag(data[,colNum],1) < data[,colNum] }
    )
    colnames(ret_sig)<-paste(label,direction,"sig",sep='.')
    return(ret_sig)
}
```

You can see that `ret_sig` is not created before it's referenced via `colnames`, so the call to `colnames` would have thrown an error.

Anyway, to fix the problem you just need to remove the `Lag(ret_sig, -1)` line. The value isn't assigned to anything, so it's not actually doing anything.

Reported and fixed in [issue #41](https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat/issues/41).